# Run Dockerfile and move the output file into local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that looks like the following.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD part_aa /data/
ADD part_ab /data/
ADD part_ac /data/
ADD part_ad /data/
ADD part_ae /data/
ADD part_af /data/
ADD part_ag /data/

CMD entrypoint.sh
```

The Dockerfile adds some files into a directory called data, and at the end entrypoint.sh merges together the files that are in the data directory into a single file.
How can I mount a volume so I can move the final output file into my local machine?
I know that I can use the -v flag (volume), but I cannot figure out how to incorporate it into running the the image.

The entrypoint.sh looks like this:

```
cd /data
MODEL_FILE="merged_file"
if [ ! -f "$MODEL_FILE" ]; then
  echo "combining model file parts."
  cat part_* > $MODEL_FILE
  echo "combining model file parts done"
fi
```

Comment: I see no benefit of using Docker here. Your part files are already on the host filesystem, where you can also cat/merge them all

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile is used to build a docker image. The -v switch is applicable when you run an image... you are mixing two things: building and running a docker image.